# Issue - Reflections do not appear when Image textures are applied on PhongMaterial in Three.js

Tags: three.js

When I apply default textures on PhongMaterial, reflections appear
fine, but, when I apply image textures on PhongMaterial the
reflections do not appear.

Please do send me your feedback on the issue. You help is highly appreciated.

Thanks for reading.

Regards,
Vijay

Answer (score 0):

You need to show some code for your problem. One for default textures and one for image textures. Frankly all textures are images so what do you mean by default textures.

Comment: I mean color called default textures. I applied image textures. i want to reflection on image textures

Comment: @gaitat Your "answer" should be a "comment" to the question, instead.